# What applications enable AirPlay mirroring for Mac?

Tags: macos, airplay

Do any applications enable AirPlay from my Mac to an Apple TV? I am looking to wirelessly mirror my Mac's display to the TV, similar to the way iPad 2 and iPhone 4S can mirror their displays over AirPlay.

Yes - it's coming as a feature for Mountain Lion, but solutions that work now on Lion are much appreciated.

Comment: Ooh, Airplay the desktop. I don't think that app exists, but it's a pretty stellar idea.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson, it would be awesome. But as usual Apple implement something quite cool, and really stable-y, but kind of stops half way. Like you should be able to AirPlay to other devices without Jailbreaking.

Comment: It's currently [Just A Rumour](http://9to5mac.com/2011/10/30/apple-looking-to-bring-airplay-mirroring-imessage-application-to-mac-os-x/), but there's talk of AirPlay mirroring coming to OS X Lion in an upcoming point release. No concrete details as yet, though. (Link via macrumors.com)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the new OSX Mountain Lion you will be able to airplay from the Mac to an Apple TV.

http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#airplay

Comment: I would like to clarify that this isn't really an Application that will allow mirroring, but the feature is announced to be incorporated into the base OS. It will be useful to keep answers around if and when apps can enable this on older / current OS like Lion.

Comment: The OP already acknowledged this fact and was asking about Lion.   Yet unfortunately, due to strict hardware requirements, it's not a simple as upgrading to Mountain Lion.  [Even the brand new Mac Pros, released only a few months _after_ you posted this answer, **do not support** AirPlay mirroring](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5404).

Answer (score 7):

[AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/) is the application you are looking for. It does exactly what you want, mirror Mac screen to AppleTV. It works on Mac OS 10.6 and higher.

Answer (score 3):

You folks might be interested in knowing about [AirVideo](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/download.html) Server, and [Airflick](http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/). The combination of these two tools will do what you want.  It will use airplay to stream wirelessly from your device to atv2, doing conversion on the fly.  airflick will send files from desktop to atv2. (And photo's, pdf's, desktop)  Very cool stuff.

Comment: AirFlick works okay, but way to few file formats are supported. Real mirroring would be great. Alternatively a VLC Plugin would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I've only been made aware of streaming it via VLC (see the post [here](http://ifoundthesolution.blogspot.com/2008/02/screencasting-using-vlc.html))

What's unknown to me is how AirPlay mirroring works. AirPlay by default supports MPEG & H.264 streams...which I believe this VLC solution will also utilize. Because of that, and the lossy nature of the codec, it won't be crisp, nor would I expect it to be fast enough for things like gaming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not airplay exactly but you can use the internet on the iPad/iPhone to access remote login, once you are in just hit mirror.

Comment: Sorry, since when did Apple TV have a browser?

Comment: OK, longer way around, using an iPhone or iPad, you can remote login and then play over airplay

Answer (score 1):

I use the iOS mirroring from my iPad with an app like [Screens](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-client-for-ios/id400012962?mt=8) to get my Mac display onto an Apple TV 2 when needed.

---

As you probably know, the only Mac direct client that sends to AirPlay are some limited apps like iTunes and Safari which send mostly video content to the AirPlay and not the whole Mac user experience including the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [aTV Flash](http://firecore.com/atvflash-black) and stream media from the network. I know this isn't exactly what the question was about, but makes the list more exhausting.

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you are after is AirFoil ( http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/ ) which you then use AirFoilSpeakers http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/ios/.

As their website says:

> Play any audio across your network to a whole host of devices, all in sync! Airfoil sends audio to remote speakers including iOS devices, other computers, and hardware devices like the Apple TV and AirPort Express. Airfoil for Mac gives you any audio, everywhere.

Comment: The question is about video, Airfoil only does audio. Classically known as "AirTunes".